# Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in select variables

Tags: r

I want to select some variables automatically, but I can't solve problem `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`.
Must be use 3 methods: forward, backward and p-value

```
library(shiny)
library(stats)
library(caret)
#created UI

server <- function(input, output) {
  data1 <- mtcars
  data2 <- mtcars
  data3 <- mtcars
  
  selected_data <- reactive({
    as.data.frame(switch(input$dataset,
                         "data1" = data1,
                         "data2" = data2,
                         "data3" = data3
    ))
  })
  
  model <- reactive({
    selected_data$x_var <- as.numeric(as.character(selected_data$x_var))
    cor_matrix <- cor(selected_data)
    max_cor_index <- which.max(cor_matrix[, "y_var"])
    max_cor_var <- colnames(selected_data)[max_cor_index]
    
    if (input$method == "forward") {
      step(lm(y_var ~ max_cor_var, data = selected_data()), direction = "forward", trace = 0)
    } else if (input$method == "backward") {
      step(lm(y_var ~ max_cor_var, data = selected_data()), direction = "backward", trace = 0)
    } else {
      library(MASS)
      stepAIC(lm(y_var ~ max_cor_var, data = selected_data()), direction = "both")
    }
    
  })
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(model())
  })
}
```

Where can be a problem, because R can't give me a clue, where is invalid data

Comment: `selected_data` is not a list/dataframe.

Comment: The line that looks bad is `selected_data$x_var <- as.numeric(as.character(selected_data$x_var))`. You can't directly edit a reactive object like that. It's not clear where `x_var` is coming from or what you are trying to accomplish with that line. But you need to make sure to keep `selected_data` a reactive object. It get it's current value you always use `selected_data()`

Comment: x_var is not nessecary, but now I have another, problem `Error in [: subscript out of bounds` and now where is the problem here